# SQL Server 2008 newest order from a specific customer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT OrdreID, KundeID, OrdreDato, Navn, Farve
FROM   Ordreliste
WHERE  Newest Order date By ????
```

I need to get the newest order date by a specific customer, but I am totally blank !

Answer (score 3):

To suggest another possibility:

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrdreID, KundeID, OrdreDato, Navn, Farve
FROM   Ordreliste
WHERE  KundeID = (your customer)
ORDER BY OrdreDato DESC
```

If the customer has two orders on the same date, you will only get one, but it may not be the latest one. If orders are entered sequentially, you can avoid this by instead ordering by `OrdreID DESC`, which should always be unique.

Comment: If I want to get the customers name, shall I then INNERJOIN my customer table??

Comment: @ErikLindbøg-Løfgreen - Yes you should

Comment: @ErikLindbøg-Løfgreen In some cases, it's better to use INNER JOIN, in others it's better to use two separate SELECT statements (which you can execute in the same batch). In this case, either works equally well, so use whichever is easiest for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest date for a specific customer you can use the [MAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933240%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) aggregate function.

```
SELECT MAX(OrdreDato)
FROM   Ordreliste
WHERE  Customer = 'YourCustomer'
```

> **MAX**
>   Returns the maximum value in the expression.

Comment: Respect my friend. U are quick.. Thx for the help

Comment: @Erik - you are welcome. If this answers your question, you can mark it as accepted. For more information about how SO works, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list of the last orders for more than 1 customer (Example: Display the last order dates for everyone from a spesific country), you can use a common table expression with a ranking function:

; WITH CTE_Last_Orders AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KundeID, ORDER BY KundeID DESC) AS LastOrder ,OrdreID, KundeID, OrdreDato, Navn, Farve 
FROM   Ordreliste 
WHERE KundeID IN ()
)
SELECT KundeID, OrdreDato FROM CTE_Last_Orders WHERE LastOrder = 1;